# how to display events side by side in fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

[image]
[image]

How can I display events side by side in fullCalendar?
The first image is my output but I need it to be like the second image. This is a fullCalendar view (fullcalendar.js).

How do I set automatic width for the events without spacing?

Comment: You appear to have used some custom CSS to shrink the width of the events from their default. Fullcalendar's rendering engine does not take account of this. Restore them to their standard width and then it will appear more like you're expecting

Comment: i can use this width . width is content wise width (auto width)

Comment: I don't really know what you mean by that, it's unclear how it relates to what I mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

FullCalendar is setting an inline CSS `inset` style on `.fc-timegrid-event-harness`, the second of which has a left value of 50% .. hence it starting half way over.

Try this for 4 on a row (25% each)

```
.fc-daygrid-event-harness, .fc-timegrid-event-harness { max-width: 25%; float: left; }

.fc-timegrid-event-harness:nth-child(1n) { inset: 0px 0% -21px 0% ! important; }
.fc-timegrid-event-harness:nth-child(2n) { inset: 0px 0% -21px 25% ! important; }
.fc-timegrid-event-harness:nth-child(3n) { inset: 0px 0% -21px 50% ! important; }
.fc-timegrid-event-harness:nth-child(4n) { inset: 0px 0% -21px 100% ! important; }
```

or for two on a row, try

```
.fc-daygrid-event-harness, .fc-timegrid-event-harness { max-width: 50%; float: left; }

.fc-timegrid-event-harness:nth-child(1n) { inset: 0px 0% -21px 0% ! important; }
.fc-timegrid-event-harness:nth-child(2n) { inset: 0px 0% -21px 50% ! important; }
```

This was previously an inline style, that I am overriding, the `-21px bottom` value came from my setup.. yours may need adjusting.

Will probably need a little adjustment to suit your sizes and styles
[image]

Comment: this is not working

Comment: which version of FullCalendar are you using?

Comment: fullcalender version 5

Comment: which view are you using? could you perhaps post some code onto Codepen?