Possible displaying events nexto each other in resourceTimelineWeek view in Fullcalendar?
Is it possible to place events next to each other instead of one below the other in Fullcalendar, like this?

I am using vueJS and tried to put two events in one and render this but this is a terrible solution... any better ideas?

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71557010/how-to-display-events-side-by-side-in-fullcalendar

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Your picture appears to be from the TimeGrid view not Timeline. Therefore you can simply use https://fullcalendar.io/docs/slotEventOverlap to get the effect in your picture.

@ADyson it is not the TimeGrid... The times to the left are my resources loaded from backend.

In that case you are completely mis-using how the calendar is supposed to work. The time axis goes horizontal in a timeline view. Having time on both axes doesn't make sense in this context. And it won't be possible to achieve what you're asking
